# How do I utilize JQuery to create a sliding effect when a box is removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slide

See my fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/nnHQp/1/

HTML:

```
 <div class="box box1"><a href=#delete">Delete</a></div>
 <div class="box box2"><a href=#delete">Delete</a></div>
 <div class="box box3"><a href=#delete">Delete</a></div>
 <div class="box box4"><a href=#delete">Delete</a></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
width: 150px;
height: 300px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.box1 {
background-color: tomato;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.box2 {
background-color: red;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.box3 {
background-color: green;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.box4 {
background-color: black;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

When one of those boxes is deleted the remaining should slide and the next one should take it's place.  How can I achieve this with JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using: <kbd>[.slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)</kbd> and <kbd>[.remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)</kbd> in a callback.

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nnHQp/20/)**</kbd>

You're missing an `"` in your HTML so should look like:

```
<div class="box box1"><a href="#delete">Delete</a></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('[href=#delete]').click(function(){
    var myParent = $(this).closest('.box');
    myParent.slideUp(800, function(){
        myParent.remove();
    });
});
```

**Another way using `.animate()`:** <kbd>**[LIVE DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/nnHQp/22/)**</kbd>

```
$('[href=#delete]').click(function(){
    var myParent = $(this).closest('.box');
    myParent.animate({width:'toggle'}, 800, function(){
        myParent.remove();
    });
});
```

Make sure to wrap your jQuery code into a `document ready` function:

```
$(function(){ // DOM is now ready to be manipulated

    // code here

});
```

Comment: Wow, thanks @roXon.  Any resource I can review to customize that sliding effect in demo #2?

Comment: @AAA depends on the way you want it "custom". Any thoughts?

Comment: would love to make the effect even smoother perhaps or something unique.

Comment: @AAA well don't ask me, first make an idea of what is "unique" :)

Comment: Gotcha.  How about it fading away and then the next box taking it's place?

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide("slow",function() {$(this).remove();});
});
```

Your html was malformed:

```
<div class="box box1"><a href="#delete">Delete</a></div>
<div class="box box2"><a href="#delete">Delete</a></div>
<div class="box box3"><a href="#delete">Delete</a></div>
<div class="box box4"><a href="#delete">Delete</a></div>
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/nnHQp/8/

Answer (score 1):

**See this**

http://jsfiddle.net/nnHQp/11/

```
   $('a').click(function(){
       $(this).parent().hide('slow');
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

An actual "slide" effect - which is not provided in the other answers - would be to animate the width, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/nnHQp/15

```
$("a").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.parent().animate({
        "width": 0
    }, 700, function() {
        $this.remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt.  I like it because it's actually mirroring a slide (not altering the width).  YMMV:

```
$('.box a[href=#delete]').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var boxes = $('.box');
    var box = $(this).parent('.box');
    box.css('visibility','hidden').next().animate({
        marginLeft: '-='+box.width()
    },400);
});
```